# How to format a date with specific locale in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is the command used when formatting a date with the browser/user locale:

```
$filter('date')(new Date(), 'MMM');
```

Problem: for a specific date element I want to always format the date in a specific locale (eg 'de'), independent of the user settings.

Question: how can I pass that locale only for this specific date?

Answer (score 0):

**Providing locale rules to Angular**

Try [angular-translate](https://angular-translate.github.io/) module for setting individual HTML element or variable using service.

Set different value based on different locale.

API: https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/

Comment: This will render all dates in the locale included. But I want to format a date in a locale that is **not** of the users locale (only one single date).

Comment: Do you want it in only in one language or in multiple language?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that JS expert, but I just finished a JS project which handeled there Dates in the backend in UTC and we show them in locale for the clients.

The best solution we found is to use momentjs.

You can find it here:

http://momentjs.com/

Comment: I'd avoid having to add another dependency, if possible.

Answer (score -2):

You should load your specific locale file as stated here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n

You can find the locale files here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/tree/master/src/ngLocale

Or installing it with bower:

```
bower install angular-i18n
```

Then just include the file in your head section:

```
<html ng-app>
 <head>
….
   <script src="angular.js"></script>
   <script src="i18n/angular-locale_de-de.js"></script>
….
 </head>
</html>
```

Comment: This will override the formatting globally, won't it? OP mentions that only certain date elements should be formatted in *de* locale.